# Link into picture - jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the easiest way to change this element:

```
<a href="pic.png">
```

Into:

```
<img src="pic.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`replaceWith`**](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$('a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<img/>').attr('src', this.href);
});
```

Replace `'a'` with the selector for the links you need replaced.

Comment: +1 I'm *always* forgetting that form (passing in a function) with methods I don't use often (like `replaceWith`). *sigh*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Me too. Till about a couple days back or so when I saw 5 or 6 answers within a couple of hours or so all using this technique here in SO. :)